# Facebook C# SDK MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, c#-4.0

i am trying to get my facebook picture by calling :

```
var user = InMemoryUserStore.Get(User.Identity.Name);
var fb = new FacebookClient(user.AccessToken);
dynamic myPhoto = fb.Get("me/picture");
```

After the call i am receiving this exception message :

Invalid JSON stringStackTrace:    at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod, Type resultType) in d:\prabir\Documents\Projects\facebooksdk\v5.4.1\Source\Facebook\FacebookClient.cs:line 479     at Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path) in d:\prabir\Documents\Projects\facebooksdk\v5.4.1\Source\Facebook\FacebookClient.cs:line 184     at CS_AspNetMvc3_WithoutJsSdk.Controllers.FacebookController.Index()

i have tried to get the picture through graph api explorer and it works.

Are you familiar with this exception and how can i retrieve my picture?

Comment: does it fail at new FacebookClient(user.AccessToken)? I wonder whether the local credentials are the same as FB.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. As a workaround I used FQL to retrieve the picture:

```
dynamic result = fb.Query("select pic_small from user where uid = " + profileId);
```

For some reason the JSON serializer in the C# Facebook SDK is unable to deserialize the GET response for a picture. If you look closely at the Graph API explorer, you'll notice its not your regular JSON being returned..